# Can't get dropdown Menu working with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used exactly as tutorials from getbootstrap and did exactly how it said but it's not working, I click on it and nothing appears.
I added Head of HTML file cause you guys told me My jquery and bootstrap CND may have problem so here it is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    
    <head>
        <title> 
            hah?
        </title>
        <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        
        
        <div class="container-fluid" id="container2">
            <a href="" id="g2glogo"></a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn-category dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
                CATEGORIES
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CURRENCY</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TOP UP</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ITEMS</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            
           
        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: did you include the bootstrap lib?

Comment: @fevid Did you also include pooper.js? From bs 4.1.0 docs: _Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js_

Comment: yes, I copied and pasted straight from getbootstrap website:

Comment: @fen1x,yes I included that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery, popper and the bootstrap JS and CSS for this to work. Here's a working snippet.

```css
.btn-category{
    background-color: #F7F7FA;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    margin: 35px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;

}
.btn-category:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn-category dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                CATEGORIES
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CURRENCY</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TOP UP</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ITEMS</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

You can find the libraries you're missing here: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I already had them included, removed mine and used yours as well, no results

Comment: The order of those imports is important. Show us your head since your code seems to be fine.

Comment: Please provide the head of your code, and also have a look in the console (press F11 to get there) and look for any errors.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the order of the file imports. Have a look at the order of mine, and try again. It's 1) jquery, 2) popper, 3) bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the javascript files at the **end of your body** tag. So don't import them in your head. Try copying and pasting below snippet. Hope this helps.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>StackOverflow</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container2">
      <a href="" id="g2glogo"></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn-category dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
          CATEGORIES
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CURRENCY</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TOP UP</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ITEMS</a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```